# Django emails with a name over 75 characters

Tags: python, django

I am having trouble sending emails because of the `sanitize_address()`
Django function.

There is a ticket who talks about this:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31784

The problem is:

In the process of sending an email the addresses is sanatized:

`django/core/mail/message.py:98 => def sanitize_address(addr, encoding)`

The Name portion is encoded via the Header class `email.header.Header.encode` which will introduce newlines at 75 characters.

Essentially Django seems to  no longer accept send emails with names longer than 75 characters.

How can I send emails with a name over 75 characters? There is a way to do
it?

I am using Django 3 and Python 3.

Comment: The ticket you show says this has been fixed in [3.0.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.0.9/)

Comment: Which version of Python3 are you using ? It is supposed to be fixed on Python 3.6.11+, 3.7.8+, and 3.8.4+.

Comment: Hello, yes, the ticket is closed and Django seems to no longer accept send emails with names longer than 75 characters. The question is: How can I send emails with a name over 75 characters? Maybe with some hack to bypass this limit.